# How to SELECT INTO array of Numbers in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to save set of ids in array:

```
declare
 cities_ids array_of_numbers;
begin
select id into cities_ids from objects where id = 1115464;
    FOR i IN 1..cities_ids.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cities_ids(i));
    END LOOP;
end;
```

After execution, I got next error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes. Expected UDT, got NUMBER.
```

Please explain what I did wrong...

Comment: Look [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/Q_26235824.html) maybe this helps you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Very simple: `BULK COLLECT` is missing.

```
declare
 cities_ids array_of_numbers;
begin
select id BULK COLLECT into cities_ids from objects where id = 1115464;
    FOR i IN 1..cities_ids.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cities_ids(i));
    END LOOP;
end;
```